# Http Session expiration

Tags: http, session, web, session-variables, jsessionid

When accessing a specific website I observe a "jsessionid" on the client side.

This identifier is used to identify the session with the server.

When does this session expire? Only when the client is inactive for a timeout-period? Or also after a fixed time (,which might be longer, say 30min.)?

Is there anyway to find out the timeout-period from the client side?

Also, is there a way to check whether the session is active?

Unfortunately, I don't know much about server side development and I could not find a clear answer in the web.

Comment: That depends on the configuration of the server. Is there any real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If you don't have access to the server side, you can't know. You can however either reverse engineer it or the cookie expiration might already be the proper time.

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes. I want to receive data from a server by using fetch()-post requests in node.js. Unfortunately, I need to do many of them (one after each other). This process might take more than one day. I wonder, whether the session can expire in this time. Is there a way to check , whether the session is active?

Comment: @maio290 how do I find out the cookie expiration? Or how can I reverse engineer?

Comment: Sounds like you’re looking for a proper API that does not rely on user sessions - try contacting the data provider

Comment: @NicoHaase   They are not providing a API.

Comment: I am asking because I am interested in how it works - not only because of my Problem. Any more hints?

Comment: "How this works" can not be answered generally - the cookie (stored in the browser) has a lifetime, and the session (stored on the server) also has a possibly different lifetime. The first lifetime can be read by you, the second one not.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to check at least cookie expiration with chrome dev tools!